# Почему AlarmManager не срабатывает ровно через заданный промежуток времени?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-alarm-manager

Почему **AlarmManager** иногда не исполняется ровно через *5 минут*, как ему полагается? Может, например, иногда не сработать - зато в следующий промежуток времени целых 2 (или 3) раза, или же отстает на 1 минуту с периодичностью в полчаса. В общем, какие-то непонятки с его работой на реальном устройстве.

**API 17**, если что (Android 4.2.1, который). Т.е. **setRepeating** должен выдавать точный интервал.

```
public void scheduleAlarm()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestAlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, TestAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 5 * 60 * 1000, pIntent); // каждые 5 минут

    Log.i(TAG_LOG, "The alarm started");
}
```

Логи:

```
<...>
17.03.2017 07:20:30
17.03.2017 07:25:30
17.03.2017 07:30:30
17.03.2017 07:40:25  <-вот
17.03.2017 07:40:30  <-вот
17.03.2017 07:45:30
17.03.2017 07:50:30
17.03.2017 07:55:30
17.03.2017 08:00:30
17.03.2017 08:10:25  <-вот
17.03.2017 08:10:30  <-вот
17.03.2017 08:15:30
17.03.2017 08:20:30
<...>
17.03.2017 16:50:30
17.03.2017 16:55:30
17.03.2017 17:01:10  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:05:30
17.03.2017 17:10:30
17.03.2017 17:15:30
17.03.2017 17:21:08  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:25:30
17.03.2017 17:40:29  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:40:29  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:40:30  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:45:30
17.03.2017 17:51:09  <-вот
17.03.2017 17:55:30
17.03.2017 18:00:50
<...>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вся проблема в том, что `Alarm Manager` не гарантирует срабатывание в заданное время. На данном [сайте](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) написано следующее:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Что переводится (вкратце):

> Начиная с API 19 срабатывание неточное. Операционная система передвигает\изменяет время срабатывания для сохранения батареи и минимизации количества пробуждений. Используйте setWindow(), если Вам нужно точное срабатывание.

Исходя из этого, Вам требуется использовать данный метод, чтобы все срабатывало именно тогда, когда нужно — [setWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

---

**UPD_0:** в силу того, что Вы используете API 17, но у Вас все равно возникают проблемы с правильностью вызова в заданное время, следует последовать следующему совету, который написан в описании метода [.setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Schedule a repeating alarm. Note: for timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler. If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.

То есть, вручную переписывать вызов кода повторения через интервал на основе [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Так у меня же API 17. Я даже это указал.

Comment: @C.Anon, прошу прощения, не заметил. Обновил ответ.

Comment: А можно чутка поподробней про **UPD_0**?

Comment: @C.Anon, *UPD_0* — это что-то вроде *UPDATE 1*, то есть *Обновление вопроса номер 1*.

Comment: Это я понял. Мне бы поподробней про сам ответ в этом обновлении.

Comment: @C.Anon, там написано, что лучше писать реализацию, которая работает на основе класса `Handler`, который вручную все отсчитывает. Последний раз с `Handler`'ом я сталкивался, когда учил основы, поэтому таким, в практике, я не занимался. Эта статья может Вам помочь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190732/android-handler-for-repeated-task-will-it-overlap-timer-task-vs-handler-vs-a

Comment: Судя по тому, что написано - Handler мне не подойдет, т.к. умрет при закрытии приложения. AlarmManager как раз по этой причине и был выбран.

Comment: @C.Anon, ну так засуньте его в сервис.